# What is the locus of points $(s,t)$ equidistant from the convex side of parabola $y = x^2$?

Tags: geometry, locus

> What is the locus of points $(s,t)$ equidistant from the convex side of parabola $y = x^2$?

Now, it is quite easy to determine s and t separately as functions of x, but can you define t as a function of s? Can it even be done?

When the question is applied to the concave side, something interesting happens.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "convex side" or "concave side". please explain. Also what do you mean by "equidistant from"? You state "quite easy to determine $s$ and $t$". If so, then please place this determination in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... If you're posing a challenge whose answer you already know, say so explicitly *in the body of the question* (as comments are easily overlooked); the predominant assumption here is that a question is a request for help, so it's important to indicate when this isn't the case. If you are in fact seeking help, then please include the work you've done (eg, easily showing $s$ and $t$ separately as functions of $x$), so that people don't waste time duplicating your effort or explaining things you already understand.

Comment: If you need help, I made this desmos graph, it isn't much but I hope it will give you some idea

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1yqxbmmlpt

Comment: This is better, use this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xwgb3ict4i

Comment: @brogine Something like this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61182/formula-for-curve-parallel-to-a-parabola ?